# OpenLayers crashes stock browser on Android 4.0.4 devices

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, android

---

**Update:** The issue appears to be with OpenLayers Release 2.13 dev. I mistakenly mentioned 2.12 as being problematic but have retested with no problems. Also, no problems with 2.13rc3

### **Update 2:** This issue appears to exist again in 2.13.1

We're developing a mapping tool using Openlayers <strike>2.1.2 (issue also confirmed on</strike> 2.1.3 <strike>).</strike>

I've tested on 4 devices running Android 4.0.4. The map panning/zooming works for a few seconds before the browser completely locks up - no longer able to pan/zoom or navigate to another page. The browser then either crashes or I need to force stop in application settings.

Devices running 4.1.1 have no problems.

This is also an issue with OpenLayers own mobile example page:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile.html

Again, after a few seconds, the browser freezes.

I see no reports of this online. The OpenLayers documentation says it is supported on Android 2.1+

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on a 4.0.4 virtual device. Maybe it is device specific? Which device(s) did you test this on?

Comment: We've tested on the following: LG Escape, Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy S3, Pantech Discover. All are running 4.0.4. Thanks.

Comment: O!  I don't have a physical device to test right now, but I'll try to get my hands on one and see.

Comment: Devdatta, see above. Issue appears to be only with 2.13 dev. Thanks again.